# Looking for a technique to call a class instance method without having a reference to the object

Tags: python, python-3.x

The module library that I am working with can call callback functions. I like to receive the callback call in an instance of a class.

I came up with the following workaround, so that when I call a callback, it calls a method of an object.

```
import gc
import random

class CallbackProofOfConcept:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state_variable = random.randint(0, 9)

    def class_methos(self, some_data):
        print(self.state_variable, some_data)

    def get_callback(self):
        def callback(some_data):
            self.class_methos(some_data)
        return callback


c1 = CallbackProofOfConcept()
c2 = CallbackProofOfConcept()

f1 = c1.get_callback()
f2 = c2.get_callback()

for i in range(100):
    print(i, "calling fx", end=' ')
    f1("f1_data")
    print(i, "calling fy", end=' ')
    f2("f2_data")
    gc.
```

Is this a proper/safe way of implementing what I need?

Is the function `callback` inside the class function `get_callback` similar to the concept of closure in Javascript?

Comment: You could just use `c1.class_methos`. No need for `get_callback`. (It's not like Javascript, where methods "forget about" `this` when you do that.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, it worked. Thanks so much !! So c1.class_methos acts like a method, and I can pass it around like a callback. Correct?